# Перенос текста из input в поле select и выбрать его

Tags: jquery, select, form, input

В сети есть способ переноса из `select` в `input`. Мне необходимо сделать наоборот
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fr3oLfga/)

```
<input type="text" value="Text" id="put"/>
<br/>
<select id="sel">
     <option></option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>2</option>
<select>
```

Comment: а куда и с какими условиями переносить?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#put').on('keyup', function() {
    inputVal = $(this).val();
    $('select#sel option[value="' + inputVal + '"]').prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
input {
  width: 170px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Text" id="put" />
<br/>
<select id="sel">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <select>
```

Comment: Да же не знаю, спасибо за оперативный ответ, но в моем случае это не работает

Comment: обращаю внимание что я `value` дописал

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, Вам требуется добавлять новые `option` в уже имеющийся список.

Можно таким способом: *(к примеру по клику на кнопку)*

```js
$("#btn").on( "click", function() { 
    $('#sel').append($('<option>', {
     text: $("#put").val(),
 }));
    $('#sel option:last-child').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-top:1em;
}
input {
    width: 170px;
    padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Text" id="put"/>
<br/>
<select id="sel">
     <option></option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>2</option>
<select>
    
<button id="btn">Вставить</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш код меня спас, все работает